# Third Monitor (Mini Display Port, Display Port)

Tags: display, amd-radeon, eyefinity

I have got a Hd 6950(2x minidisplay port 2x DVI port 1x HDMI port) graphic cards. And I have got a three monitor. I want to active it all.

I learned to need an active minidisplay port to vga or minidisplay port to dvi cable. Here's my problem. I want to buy minidisplay port to dvi but my country doesn't have it but I can find display port to active dvi cable.

I have a minidisplay port to display port cable. If I buy Sapphire ACTİVE DP TO SL-DVİ CABLE will my third monitor work? I mean I will plug mini display port to display port cable first and after I will plug active dp to dvi cable.

Will it work? If someone help me I will be very grateful.

I have this

[image]

And I will buy this

[image]

After this processing Will my third monitor work with eyefinity?

Sorry for my English. I hope you will understand me. Take care.

Comment: *>  I want to buy minidisplay port to dvi but my country doesn't have it*   Can you use eBay? If so, you can get whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

The regular display port adapter WILL NOT work with HD 6950.

I have three monitors connected to my XFX Radeon HD6950 and I have to use a "mini" displayport to DVI for my third monitor. Whether it's "active" or not only matters if you plan on using EYEFINITY, where you can turn three monitors into one.

Can't you order from Amazon?

YOU DO WANT the "active" displayport since you do plan to use EYEFINITY, but you also NEED a "mini" for the 6950. A regular displayport connecter, which is wider then a mini will not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

favorite
1

I have got a Hd 6950(2x minidisplay port 2x DVI port 1x HDMI port) graphic cards. And I have got a three monitor. I want to active it all.

> I learned to need an active mini-displayport to vga or 
>   mini-displayport to dvi cable. Here's my problem.

If you want to use eyefinity then yes, you either need a displayport cabable monitor (probably the best solution) or an active DP to somethign convertor. (Where the something is obviously a format which your monitor supports as input).

> I want to buy mini-displayport to DVI but my country doesn't have it
>   but I can find display port to active dvi cable.

Actibe convertors used to be either expensive and or rare. They no longer are. Neiher are monitors supporting DP port. I guess this changed in the last four years.

For people reading this late answer: The relative unexpesive option is now a DP capable monitor compared to an active convertor to an ancient monitor.

> I have a mini-displayport to displayport cable.

A cable is just a passive part. In this case it does not change anything. DP and mini DP are the same except for the form factor.

> If I buy Sapphire ACTİVE DP TO SL-DVİ CABLE will my third monitor work?

**It should work provided that it is an active device**.
Despite the word active being mentioned on the front I have serious doubts about it. Most active devices require at least some power input to drive their circuitry. Many advertise it even more blantantly. This one might just be passive with marketing speech attached.

Note that it mentions SL-DVI. SINGLE LINK. Slingle link has limited bandwidth, limiting it to resolutions sunch as 1920 × 1200  @ 60 Hz.